# never seen for loop this way how does this work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am just reading through a book but it didn't mention using `for` this way.  The most common way I can understand but this I have no idea how it start and end.

this is a function which has a for loop in it and what's being inserted into the argument is an object which inherits objects and objects like a list.

```
function listToArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest)
    array.push(node.value);
  return array;
}

var object = {
    value: 10,
    rest: {
        value: 20,
        rest: {
            value: 30,
            rest: null
        }
    }
}

console.log(listToArray(object));
// → [10, 20, 30]
```

`for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest)` this is the part where I don't understand how it works.  How it start or end.

I just have a simple guess myself to start off, node is an object so if `node != null` then `node = list` and `node = node.rest` which is the next object

Comment: Looks like a linked list

Comment: Your guess is right `for(initial; condition; action)`

Comment: @hofan41 ah! alright, the book did mention list but didn't say it's called a linked list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A for loop take three arguments:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

`var node = list;` runs when the loop is started.

`node` is the condition, if it is false, the loop won't go around again.

`node = node.rest` is run at the end of the loop.

So:

It sets `node` to `list` and then keeps replacing `node` with the value of the previous nodes `rest` property.

Eventually `node` is `{ value: 30, rest: null }`, so it sets `node` to `null` then tests if `null` is `true` and then stops because it isn't.

Comment: alrighty, thanks.  My guess isn't so bad after all :D never thought of using it this way.  It's cool! I will mark the answer in few minutes when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

Like in any other c based language, for loop is basically formed this way: `for(initialization;condition;incrementation)`

In this code, the initialization part is defining a new var named node, and initializing it´s value to the same as the argument `list`.

The condition part `node` in javascript means, while node != null (or unassigned)

The incrementation part is setting node to the value of `node.rest`.
I dunno what node.rest does, but I suppose it will move to the next node in the tree/graph.

So in this case, the for starts when list is assigned, and ends when node.rest returns null/unassigned.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually, really interesting! But what you have here is a for loop used in a pretty creative way to iterate deeper into an object.

`for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest)`

If we think about for loops in a traditional sense, something like

`for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

We can draw a few parallels.

If you look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for a for loop, you see that it's broken up into three sections:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

**Initialization** -- Specify variables, etc that will be used at the start of the loop, in this case our starting node is equal to the `list` passed in.

**Condition** -- Now here's something a little different, but basically this middle statement is condition to determine if the loop should execute. Most of the time you see `i < 10` or some numeric comparison because that's a common use case. This example is leveraging the truthiness of objects in javascript. That is, an object, taken by itself evaluates to `true`.

ex. `if({}) // will be true` The fact that `node` is placed there by itself is basically saying "Look at the truthiness of `node`, if the object exists, then let's run the loop! Otherwise `node` will be `undefined`, and `undefined` is a falsey value in javascript.

Lastly we have the final expression, or what I like to call the 'update' section. We're essentially assigning `node` to be equal to its child property, which means we're iteratively going deeper and deeper into these objects. if `node.rest` exists, then the next iteration of the loop will start there and run itself again if `node.rest` actually existed in the previous loop.

Good question. I enjoyed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Boolean(object.rest); //true
Boolean(object.rest.rest); //true
Boolean(object.rest.rest.rest); //false
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! While this may answer the question, it's a bit criptic, and code only. Can you take some time explaining what you mean? tx